# Tidy class not found

Tags: php, tidy

I've been using using Tidy just by enabling its extension in php.ini (in XAMPP, WINDOWS OS)
I'm trying to do the same on XAMPP,macOS by enabling the Tidy extendion in the php.ini which is located in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini but I still get php error when i try to instantiate the tidy class:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "tidy" not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/core/functions.php:48 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/models/user.php(402): truncate('James is a powe...', 200) #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/views/joacmedia/temp/us.php(237): User->truncate('James is a powe...', 200) #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/views/joacmedia/temp/us.php(283): Page->sectionIntro(Object(stdClass)) #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/views/joacmedia/temp/us.php(34): Page->LayoutBottomAream(Object(stdClass)) #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/views/joacmedia/temp/us.php(355): Page->__construct(Array) #5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/core/controller.php(11): include('/Applications/X...') #6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/views/joacmedia/us.php(5): Controller->view('joacmedia/temp/...', Array) #7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/core/controller.php(11): include('/Applications/X...') #8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/controllers/us.php(47): Controller->view('joacmedia/us', Array) #9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/core/app.php(61): Us->index('jay') #10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/index.php(6): App->__construct() #11 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joacmedia/app/core/functions.php on line 48`

what should i do to get this error fixed ?

`

```
//add ellipsis to string
    function truncate($html,$length){
        $tidy = new tidy();
        if ((int)mb_strlen($html,'UTF-8') >= (int)$length ) {
          $ellipsis = "<div class='ellipsis_show'>
                        <div data-href='false' class='text-right see_more_text text-secondary'><strong>...</strong>see more</div>
                      </div>";
            
          return trim((strip_empty_tag(convert_ENCODE($tidy->repairString("<span data-show-summary='true'>".(NewLineToBreak(substr(trim($html),0,$length)))."</span>"."<span class='text_exposed_hide hide visually_hidden'>".trim(NewLineToBreak(substr($html,$length)))."</span>"),'UTF-8')))).$ellipsis;
        }

        return trim((strip_empty_tag(convert_ENCODE(tidy_repair_string(NewLineToBreak($html)),'UTF-8'))));
      }
```

`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a new tidy() in your function and I suspect you do not have the tiny class defined in the same file or namespace. If you use namespaces you shoud do the use your/namespace/to/tiny or you should do a require/include in your functions.php file to include the desired tiny class file.

Comment: I don't need to defined a custom class when using php tidy. I always just enable this extension in the php.ini
extension=php_tidy.dll

Comment: check this example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.php

Comment: i also checked if the tidy extension is loaded or not: echo extension_loaded('tidy') ? "LOADED" : "NOT LOADED";